# What should I call the part of car that influences the orientation of the wheels by moving left/right?

Tags: translation

I want to know the English word for *stuurhuis* as shown in the following picture:

[image: Depiction of an automotive steering system with Dutch part names]

Comment: Your *car mechanic* might call it a *rack and pinion unit*, but ordinary people (if they refer to it at all) normally just call it the [**steering rack**](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5039068_steering-rack.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it's **"the rack and pinion unit"**. **[image: "rack and pinion unit"]**.

> - A rack and pinion is commonly found in the steering mechanism of cars or other wheeled, steered vehicles. Rack and pinion provides a less efficient mechanical advantage than other mechanisms such as recirculating ball, but less backlash and greater feedback, or steering "feel". The mechanism may be power-assisted, usually by hydraulic or electrical means. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_and_pinion)

- [picture 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009LN5HQY)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that part is a Rack and Pinion unit (sometimes shortened to "rack and pinion" on the sad occasions my mechanic has discussed it with me). Here's a similar picture of a steering system with the parts labeled in English.

[image]

Comment: I think your picture show it is the "Rack & Pinion Unit". Google images indicates this as well. I was able to do a query because of the image you added. Thanks. Stuurhuis images: https://www.google.nl/search?q=stuurhuis+auto&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=700&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIuejZ6saFxwIVQlrbCh2bYgU9  . rack & pinion unit umages: https://www.google.nl/search?q=rack+%26+pinion+unit&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=700&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCkQsARqFQoTCLbEt83GhccCFWOa2wodLdgDnQ#tbm=isch&q=rack+%26+pinion+unit+car . I am almost sure.

Comment: That's what it looks like to me too (now that I can see the picture). I'll update the answer.